# LINQ Linq2Sql Queryable SelectMany InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
// usual stuff
var medias = Medias.Where(a => !a.Removed);


 // Find the last date in our collection
 var lastDateWithValues = medias.Select(a => a.Date).Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).Select(a => a.Date).FirstOrDefault();

 // Group collection by Property
 var myQuery = (from m in medias
 group m by m.PropertyId into mg
 // filter last 12 month and group by our TypeId
 let lastValues = mg.Where(f => f.Date > lastDateWithValues.AddMonths(-12)).GroupBy(x => x.MediaTypeId)
 // check if this any of this "TypeGroup" has 12 or month values
 let hasTwelve = lastValues.Where(a => a.Count() >= 12)
 // if it has 12 or more values in any of those groups, return values flatten. If not, return empty
 let results = hasTwelve.Any() ? lastValues.SelectMany(x => x) : Enumerable.Empty<Media>().AsQueryable()
 select results);
```

This works fine, but now i want to flatten this with a SelectMany:

```
 var dontWork = myQuery.SelectMany(x => x);

 var worksFine = myQuery.ToList().AsQueryable().SelectMany(x => x);
```

Is there anyway I can rewrite myQuery so I dont need to use ToList() to make it work?

Thanks,

Edit2: Rewritten with help from taemyr:

```
var lastDateWithValues = medias.Select(a => a.Date).Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).FirstOrDefault();
var mediaDataRange = medias.Where(f => f.Date > lastDateWithValues.AddMonths(-12));
var fullProperties = mediaDataRange.GroupBy(x => new { x.PropertyId, x.MediaTypeId}).Where(x => x.Count() >= 12).Select(x => x.Key.PropertyId).Distinct().ToList();
var result = mediaDataRange.Where(x => fullProperties.Contains(x.PropertyId));
```

Edit:

This is tested using LinqPad 4 with SQL Connection Linq2SQL
Net Framework 4.6.1

Full error message from LinqPad:
Could not format node 'ClientQuery' for execution as SQL

```
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitClientQuery(SqlClientQuery cq)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitSearchedCase(SqlSearchedCase c)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias alias)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitJoin(SqlJoin join)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect ss)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Visitor.Format(SqlNode node, Boolean isDebug)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFormatter.Format(SqlNode node)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(ResultShape resultShape, Type resultType, SqlNode node, ReadOnlyCollection parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
vid System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
vid System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
vid LINQPad.UI.ExplorerGrid.ConvertToList(IEnumerable source)
vid LINQPad.UI.ExplorerGrid.UpdateDataSourceToUse()
```

Comment: Your `dontWork` raises an `InvalidOperationException`? What is the full error text?

Comment: What error message do you get.  And what do you hope to accomplish with SelectMany(x=>x)?

Comment: Error message: Could not format node 'ClientQuery' for execution as SQL

Comment: Accomplish: I want the query to stay as a IQueryable due to performance

Comment: So it's not a general LINQ, but query provider specific question. What is the query provider type - i.e. EF6, EF Core etc.?

Comment: LinqPad 4 with SQL Connection Linq2SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not grouping.

```
 // filter last 12 month and group by our TypeId
 let lastValues = mg.Where(f => f.Date > lastDateWithValues.AddMonths(-12))
 let lastValuesGrouped=lastValues.GroupBy(x => x.MediaTypeId)
 // check if this any of this "TypeGroup" has 12 or month values
 let hasTwelve = lastValuesGrouped.Where(a => a.Count() >= 12)
 // if it has 12 or more values in any of those groups, return values flatten. If not, return empty
 let results = hasTwelve.Any() ? lastValues : Enumerable.Empty<Media>().AsQueryable()
```

Edit: Pr comment this does not resolve the issue; however it removes a layer of indirection and makes it easier to troubleshoot the issue.

The issue is that the tertiary expression hides the type, leaving the provider with only an enumerable to work with.  A potential solution is to avoid the tertiary.

```
 let lastValues = mg.Where(f => f.Date > lastDateWithValues.AddMonths(-12))
 let lastValuesGrouped=lastValues.GroupBy(x => x.MediaTypeId)
 let hasTwelve = lastValuesGrouped.Where(a => a.Count() >= 12).Select(x=>x.Key)
 let results = lastValues.Where(x=>hasTwelve.Contains(x.MediaTypeId)
```

Comment: Nope, same error. Tried alot of different ways but same error.

Comment: @Tom Hmm.  OK - That let me recreate the problem. Suggestion improved.

Comment: OK Thanks, solved by rewriting the query using contains like you suggested. Check my edit if you are interested.

Comment: @Tom if my answer solved your issue please accept the answer.